# Angular share data between components using service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I'm trying to share data between components using service. 
In `project` component there is an click event on button

```
<button type="submit" (click)="newValue()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mt-2">Create task</button>
```

which should emit a string value

```
newValue() {
    this.shareService.changeValues("Hello from project");
  }
```

In service I'm trying to get an `observable` on  `BehaviorSubject`

```
 private selectedValue = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  currentValue = this.selectedValue.asObservable();
```

`Task` component has subscription, but value isn't updated.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-using-service)

Answer (score 0):

In the service you need to do `.next` on the `BehaviorSubject` i.e. `BehaviorSubject` when the `changeValues` methos is called.
Please refer the code below

In `ShareService`

```
changeValues(value: string) {
    this.selectedValue.next(value);
}
```

Better way to handle this is to return `Observable` to which we can subscribe to get values.

```
@Injectable()
export class ShareService{
   selectedValue = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

   getSelectedValue$() {
      return this.selectedValue.asObservable();
   }
   changeValues(value: string) {
        this.selectedValue.next(value);
    }
}
```

Whereever we need the `SelectedValue`, we Inject this `Service` and `subscribe` to the `Observable` rettrurned from `getSelectedValue$` method.
In the `Task` component

```
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(
       public ShareService: ShareService) {
   }
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ShareService.getSelectedValue$().subscribe((selectedValue)=> {
        // use selectedValue here
    })
  }
}
```